# Обновление данных в dropdown через другую activity

Tags: java, android-studio, android-spinner

Сразу к делу:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText ename,eroll_no,emarks/*, gr*/;
Button add,view,viewall,delete,modify, groupe, addcat;
Spinner gr;
SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ename = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    eroll_no = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.roll_no);
    emarks = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.marks);
    //gr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.gr);
    gr = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);// сам спиннер из вида
    add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbtn);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("Student_manage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(rollno INTEGER UNIQUE,name VARCHAR,marks INTEGER,groupe VARCHAR);");
    //вот я пытаюсь сделать:
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM groups", null);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor, new String[] {"name"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    gr.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//не работает
}
}
```

Вопрос. Сейчас когда я заполняю данные во второй активности и потом перехожу в MainActivity, в spinner они не обновляются. Когда захожу заново в приложение, все обновляется. Как сделать, чтобы они сразу обновлялись там?

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Это не работает.

Полазив в интернете, я понял, что:

Данные в другой активити не обновятся, потому что я не передал туда обновлённые данные.

А при повторном запуске приложения всё читается, т.к. я сохраняю в БД и полностью вывожу ее содержимое. Пытался сделать так:
В MainActivity при переходе на другую активити startActivityForResult(...)

затем в MainActivity переопределить метод onActivityResult(...), в котором обработать обновлённые данные. Эти данные надо положить в Intent в SecondActivity при переходе в MainActivity. Я попытался это реализовать, но не вышло. 
Вот вторая активити:

```
adds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(ename.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || eroll_no.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 )
            {
                showMessage("Ошибка", "Заполните поля");
                return;
            }
            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE rollno='"+eroll_no.getText()+"'", null);
            if(c.getCount()>0) {
                showMessage("Ответ:", "Такой ID уже есть!");
            }else {
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO groups(rollno, name) VALUES('" + eroll_no.getText() + "','" + ename.getText() +"');");
                showMessage("Ответ:", "Запись успешно добавлена!");

                Cursor cursors = db.query("groups", new String[]{"_id","name"}, null, null, null, null, null);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("name", cursors.toString());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
            clearText();
        }
    });
```

Здесь я пытался передать новый запрос (сделал строкой его).
Вот MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data == null) {return;}
    String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
    что делать далее я не знаю.... можете подсказать?
}
//это кнопка перехода во вторую активити
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GroupActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужно передавать данные в активити, вам нужно сохранить их в БД в том месте, где вы их получили, а потом прочитать в другой активити уже обновленные данные прямо из БД.

Сделать это можно в методе `onResume()` активити, которая должна показать новые данные (в вашем случае `MainActivity`)/ Этот метод вызывается всякий раз, когда активити выходит на передний план (становится видима на экране).

Чтобы не писать дублирующийся код, разделим инициализацию адаптера на два этапа:

- 1 этап - создание адаптера и получение виджетов, в методе `onCreate()`, чтобы при каждом возврате на активити на передний план у нас не создавались новые объекты
- 2 этап - получение данных, в методе `onResume()`. Данные в адаптере будут обновляться каждый раз, когда активити выходит на передний план.

Так же для обновления `CursorAdapter` (и его наследников) используется метод `swapCursor()` или `changeCursor()` аргументом которого указывается курсор с обновленными данными, а не `notifiDataSetChenged()`.

В **MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {

     ...
     SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM groups", null);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null, new String[] {"name"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        gr.setAdapter(adapter);
       // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Закомментированные строки следует удалить. Адаптер переносим в поле класса, для доступа к нему по всей активити. При создании адаптера указываем Cursor = null, данные мы добавим позже.

Обновляем данные в адаптере при появлении активити на переднем плане:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM groups", null);
     adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
}
```

переопределение метода `onActivityResult()` не требуется.

PS: вы не можете передавать курсор в виде строки (`cursor.toString()`) и надеяться, что после этого что то будет работать.